# Memcache database queries

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, redis, memcached

I am very new to Scaling databases, but I have seen a lot of companies use Memcache to speed up loading times.

**Question:** How do you use memcache to save data personlized to a user that does update, like user feed or favourites? Do you store database tables or per user queries?

I know about indexing but if I can save an expensive query I want to find out how!

Comment: Are you familiar with `caching` concept? If not, please go through laravel cache https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/cache#configuration

Answer (score 0):

1. You identify that data with a key indexed to that user, like `user-feed-12701` or `favourites-12701`, and flush it from the cache based on that key when it updates.
2. Per user query results.